# Getting the Lua syntax tree with liblua

Tags: c++, parsing, lua, abstract-syntax-tree

Is it possible to get the syntax tree with liblua?

I need the AST of lua code, but I can't depend on ANTLR4, so I'm looking for a self contained solution. Since my host app already embeds lua, liblua would be perfect.

If not with liblua, what other options are there for parsing Lua in C++?

Answer (score 0):

The built-in Lua parser is a one-pass compiler which directly generates Lua VM instructions. No AST is created, and it would be more complicated to decompile the VM code into an AST than to create a parser using whatever parser generator you feel comfortable with.

For example, Bison produces perfectly acceptable C++ code without requiring any run-time. It has a C++ API but it is also possible to use the C template and compile the result as a C++ program.